# How to enable/disable Angular Kendo Combobox programatically or even by html markup

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am trying to disable/enable `kendo Combobox` based on the text enterted in `searchString` text box.
If text is entered, then `combobox` should be disabled and if no text is there in `searchString` then only the `combobox` should be enabled.
Here is the ***[DOJO Link](http://dojo.telerik.com/@paritosh/ACOro)***

```
<input type='search' ng-model='searchString' />
<div style="padding-top: 1em;">
    <h4>Remote data</h4>
    <select kendo-combo-box k-enable='!(searchString && searchString.length > 0)'
            k-placeholder="'Select product'"
            k-data-text-field="'ProductName'"
            k-data-value-field="'ProductID'"
            k-filter="'contains'"
            k-auto-bind="false"
            k-min-length="3"
            k-data-source="productsDataSource"
            style="width: 100%" >
    </select>
</div>
```

I know the functionality is possible with `jQuery`,

```
$('#id').kendoComboBox({ enabled: true });
```

But how to do this with Angular JS? I can keep `$watch()` in angular controller for `searchString`, but the question is how to disable the `combobox` with Angular JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

`Kendo UI` creates a new `$scope` variable when we provide the value for the `kendo-combo-box`.
As per below, `myCombobox`

```
<select kendo-combo-box='myCombobox' 
            k-placeholder="'Select product'"
            k-data-text-field="'ProductName'"
            k-data-value-field="'ProductID'"
            k-filter="'contains'"
            k-auto-bind="false"
            k-min-length="3"
            k-data-source="productsDataSource">
</select>
```

We can use the same `$scope` variable in the controller to disable it.

```
$scope.myCombobox.enable(false);
```

I have updated the same ***[DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@paritosh/ACOro)***

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-disabled`

Example:

```
<select
    kendo-combo-box="projectCombobox"
    k-data-source="projectDataSource"
    k-data-text-field="'code'"
    k-data-value-field="'projectId'"
    k-value-primitive="true"
    k-ng-model="checklist.projectId"
    k-suggest="true"
    k-filter="'contains'"
    k-change="onProjectChange"
    style="width: 100%" 
    ng-disabled="!DriveTagSelected">
</select>

ng-disabled="!DriveTagSelected"
```

Here you can define a variable based on your condition.

Comment: you can define that if there is text in your `searchString` then apply true to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

a new better way is now available by using `k-ng-disabled`, you won't need to `$watch` the variable

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#state-changes